# How can I access a variable from the Bootstrap file in my controllers in Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon, jwt

I'm using JWT to authenticate a request, and I'm doing all the authentication in the Bootstrap file by writing a new method. If the authentication is successful, I want the variables in the payload of the JWT to be accessible in my controllers. Since this is not a config, I cannot use the standard ways to get config to your controllers. What do I do?

Comment: post some of your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set them as a shared resource.

```
$di->setShared('jwtAuth', function() {
    // result from your logic
    return $jwtAuth ;
});
```

And then you can use jwtAuth everywhere you want, controllers, models, views, helpers e.t.c.

Comment: Can you share the portion of your code where you set the service, perhaps update your question description with code? Also are you sure everything in your logic works as intended?